# Reading docker environmental variables through react-env plugin for a dockerize React application?

Tags: reactjs, bash, docker

I have a docker container with a few environment variables setup. I know that in a typical use case, React is unable to read these variables as the `process.env` variables are replaced during transpiling.

I am trying to work around this without having to spin up a back-end server by using a plugin called [react-env](https://github.com/beam-australia/react-env).

The core idea is to create a `.env` file which can be written to using a `bash` script. The `bash` script will copy any environmental variables to the `.env` file. The plugin will generate a `env.js` file which then will be consumed by the React application at runtime.

In my setup I created two sample environmental variables.

- `REACT_APP_SETUP="OK"` - hardcoded in the `.env` file.
- `REACT_APP_GCP_PROJECT_ID="SOMEID"` - to be written by the bash file.

**.env**

```
# .env
REACT_APP_SETUP="OK" //prewritten env for testing.
```

**docker-entrypoint.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
printf "\n" >> /usr/app/.env

//env that is supposed to be copied.
printf 'REACT_APP_GCP_PROJECT_ID="%s"' SOMEID >> /usr/app/.env 
serve build
```

**Dockerfile**

```
# Base version
FROM node:9

# Install yarn
RUN npm install yarn

# Install serve.js
RUN yarn global add serve

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/app

# Copy all necessary files and grant permissions.
# - yarn.lock
# - package.json
# - .env
# - docker-entrypoint.sh
COPY . /usr/app/
COPY yarn.lock /usr/app
COPY package.json /usr/app
COPY .env /usr/app
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/app/docker-entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod 777 /usr/app/docker-entrypoint.sh

# Install dependencies.
RUN yarn

# Build application.
RUN yarn build

# Set entrypoint of application.
ENTRYPOINT [ "/usr/app/docker-entrypoint.sh" ]
```

**App.jsx**

```
...

console.log(env("SETUP"));
console.log(env("GCP_PROJECT_ID"));

...
```

**Inspect Console**

```
OK
undefined
```

In the example setup above, we can see the plugin works as the dockerized application does generate the `env.js` for the React app hence the `OK` console output.

However, I cannot seem to get the bash file to write to the `.env` file thus the `undefined` console output.

`exec`ing into the container also shows the `.env` file having both `REACT_APP_GCP_PROJECT_ID="SOMEID"` and `REACT_APP_SETUP="OK"` entries.

I suspect that the `env.js` is being generated before the bash file has a chance to write to the `.env` file.

**How can i write to my `.env` file such that the plugin can generate a `env.js` file which my application can read environmental variables from?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to write to the file before building the app:

```
FROM node:9

# Install yarn
RUN npm install yarn

# Install serve.js
RUN yarn global add serve

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/app

# Copy all necessary files and grant permissions.
# - yarn.lock
# - package.json
# - .env
# - docker-entrypoint.sh
COPY . /usr/app/
COPY yarn.lock /usr/app
COPY package.json /usr/app
COPY .env /usr/app
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/app/docker-entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod 777 /usr/app/docker-entrypoint.sh

# Install dependencies.
RUN printf "\n" >> /usr/app/.env
RUN printf 'REACT_APP_GCP_PROJECT_ID="%s"' SOMEID >> /usr/app/.env 
RUN yarn

# Build application.
RUN yarn build

# Set entrypoint of application.
ENTRYPOINT [ "/usr/app/docker-entrypoint.sh" ]
```

and your entrypoint:

```
#!/bin/sh 
serve build
```